# ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel - No DataContext for MainWindow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, prism-5

MainWindow UI

```
<Window x:Class="PrismSanity.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName}"></TextBlock>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {

        private string _MyName = "John";

        public string MyName
        {
            get { return _MyName = "John"; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _MyName, value); }
        }


    }
```

I installed SNOOP to see what was happening, but the VM is not being Linked to the View. If I do the same thing with a second view, and use

```
<ContectContainer>
<views:ViewA/>
</ContentContainer>
```

in the Mainwindow
Then I get the ViewA and ViewAViewModel to link fine.
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3):

Prism supports only `UserControl` class not `Window` class. `AutoWireViewModel` wokrs only with `UserControl` class.

I have the same problem I resolve this binding the context in code behind - partial using Unity. Something like that:

```
public partial class ShellView : Window
{
    public ShellView(ShellViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Set the ViewModel as this View's data context.
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
```

When app create the ShellView (it is your PrismSanity.MainWindow) unity inject the viewModel (`ShellViewModel` )

It is little technology debt.

Comment: There is a way to do this with out the code behind, I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY And can get as far as the selecting the Views, but it never Links the VM to the MainWindow.

Comment: <Window x:Class="PrismSanity.MainWindow">
Should be updated to <Window x:Class="PrismSanity.Views.MainWindow">
Once I updated that the program worked Right