# Prism ICommand from region to shell

Tags: c#, design-patterns, prism

I trying to create some regions, and in one of that regions, I have button "login" and `ICommand Login` property it is bound to. So I want to subscribe to this `Login` from shell.

I tried `PubSubEvent`, but I also need `CanExecute` method.

Another solution I have found, is to use static class with static commands. This I think is not a good pattern.

How to do this right from pattern perspective?

**EDIT 1**

To assign a region, I invoke this in constractor of shell's view model:

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainContent", typeof(LoginArea));
```

And in view I use this `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`, so I could not inject my shell's view model to subscribe events to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could communicate between different modules in a decoupled way using the event aggregator. There is an example available on GitHub here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/EventAggregation/Desktop/ModuleA/AddFundPresenter.cs. If you want the basics on the event aggregator pattern and how it is applied in Prism, you could refer to the following blog post: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/.

The other option is to use a shared service: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22907a0f-d805-4195-8272-7c284b72d2ee/example-of-using-shared-services-prism?forum=wpf. A shared service is simply a class that provides functionality to several modules in a decoupled way. It should implement an interface and you register it with container in your bootstrapper, typically as a singleton.

> And in view I use this ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True", so I could not inject my shell's view model to subscribe events to it.

Well, if you don't want the shell's view model to be injected with any dependencies at all you will have to use some kind of static class to get a reference to the EventAggregator or the shared service. There is an example of how you could expose the EventAggregator from a static class available here: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/

But you could easily inject the shell window with whatever dependencies you need by overriding the  InitializeShell() method of your Bootstrapper, e.g.:

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IEventAggregator), typeof(EventAggregator), true);
        Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>());
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

The ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel property is meant to be used for UserControl views anyway:

[ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel - No DataContext for MainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125315/viewmodellocator-autowireviewmodel-no-datacontext-for-mainwindow)

But, speaking of patterns, you should probably consider moving your shell view model class to a module and keep the shell window as a true shell that is made up of child views.